# Layout file not loading any css or javaScript in laravel

Tags: javascript, css, laravel

I have a resource controller and none of the views related to them has any javascript or CSS. And the fact is that it loads the layout file which is correct for any other views not related to the resource. 
And here is another thing. When I comment the resource route and write a route like this :

```
 Route::get('/create', 'ToursController@create');
```

The page loads CSS but when I write like this:

```
`Route::get('/tours/create', 'ToursController@create');`
```

it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not working because you are including it without `asset()`

try like this

```
<link href="{{ asset('path/to/css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

and for JavaScript

```
<script src="{{ asset('assets/js/jquery.slimscroll.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, sir! It really helped me out.

Comment: And thank you for the edit as well! It was my first question ever here and I didn't know how to write properly.

Comment: @Capt.BlackBearD Welcome